# Google maps draw route from given coordinates

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, coordinates

I am using `google-maps-react` module and everything until the last stretch is fine. Using this package, I am able to click on map, set multiple markers and define my route "visually". I did not think that `Polygon` would not take actual streets and map geometry into consideration (stupid me). Could someone help me out and suggest on how to provide properly drawn routes on map, instead of straight lines connecting marker X to marker Y? This is what I have so far visually:

[image]

And this is the coordinates array that I am forming in my application and drawing polygon by:

[image]

**I am using Google maps api and `google-maps-react` package.**

Comment: For showing the actual routes  you need to make a direction API call for routing. Polygons or lines are not following streets and the actual routes as you have seen. It's fairly streghtforward and you simply need to do something like below. Keep in mind, You will have an origin, a destination and if you need stops in between those are called waypoints. In total, you can have 25, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing

Comment: @TheeBen, thanks. But can you make requests using `fetch` to destination api? I form a request, try to fetch it and I get back an undefined response, although the url I am requesting is 100% fine as I am able to see json data if I input it plainly into the browser.

Comment: add the code to show how you are making the request, your fetch method or whatever you are using. Also make sure you haven't restricted your API key to a specific service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was correctly mentioned in comment,  [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) needs to be utilized for that purpose:

> Directions are displayed as a polyline drawing the route on a map, or
>   additionally as a series of textual description within a  element
>   (for example, "Turn right onto the Williamsburg Bridge ramp")

The following example demonstrates how to integrate `Google Maps API Directions Service` into `google-maps-react` to display a route.

> It is assumed `data` prop contains coordinates represented in format
>   specified in provided question. Directions Service code has been adapted
>   from [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)

**Example**

```
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMapReady = this.handleMapReady.bind(this);
  }

  handleMapReady(mapProps, map) {
    this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(map);
  }

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(map) {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


    const waypoints = this.props.data.map(item =>{
      return{
        location: {lat: item.lat, lng:item.lng},
        stopover: true
      }
    })
    const origin = waypoints.shift().location;
    const destination = waypoints.pop().location;

    directionsService.route({
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      waypoints: waypoints,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) => {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="map-container">
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          className={"map"}
          zoom={this.props.zoom}
          initialCenter={this.props.center}
          onReady={this.handleMapReady}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-iylbfo)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this page
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

The response from that API call with the data you've already gotten from the lines drawn should give you the JSON data you need to map your path to the roads. This might not be the most elegant solution seeing as you might need to add a button or something to calculate the route to roads or something similar.

Alternatively you might be able to send out the API call after you have two points and have the map update after every line segment is placed. That would require a lot of API calls though. Hope that helps!